# Cordova InAppBrowser inception: Open a child window inside the original InAppBrowser window?

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, cross-domain, inappbrowser

*Sorry for the confusing phrasing - this is about the third level of Cordova inception: a nested window, within an InAppBrowser window, within a CordovaWebView!*

Here's what I am trying to accomplish in a Cordova/Phonegap project:

1. Load a remote page within an InAppBrowser window, then...
2. **Let the remote page open a child window within the InAppBrowser** (via window.open()) that it has control over like in a normal browser environment (and can use window.postMessage to communicate with)

The problem is that from within the InAppBrowser, I don't know of a way to allow window.open() to create a child window of the original page inside the InAppBrowser. The only behaviors I can choose are opening the link in the *same* window in the InAppBrowser, or opening the link in the external browser app.

**Is there a way to open the link as a child window of the first page, within the InAppBrowser**?

The actual use-case is that our app has a remote login screen for OAuth (which we load in the first InAppBrowser window) that in turn allows social login (via [Gigya](http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/10_UM360#Web_Wireframes_for_Best_Practice_Implementation)) that works by opening a child window controlled by the social login providers.  The child window ultimately sends a message to the parent with the auth information required to close the loop. This mechanism fails because we can't open that child window as a *child* within the InAppBrowser and so the message can't be passed.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: I'm afraid not!  We worked around the limitation.  (IIRC we found something that _might_ have worked, involving capturing the click of the link aimed for the double-nested window and instead passing that up and opening it in an iframe in the root webview... I might be off on the deatails.  Obviously that doesn't sound very robust so we abandoned it)